# Safari showing website in different language than what's set in Preferences

Tags: macos, language

Surfing around found a web site I needed info. from. It's in Japanese Language.  Whats w/ that? Safari is browser, an it's set with English as language, in Region Setting preferences.

Is there no changing the Web page language and shouldn't all language on this Mac be in English if Regional options have been set U.S.A.?

Comment: Seriously folks...why the barrage of down votes?  People come here to learn, not brow beaten over what they do not know.  +1 for putting this out there

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different, Taylor. I second Allan and also wanted to remind that one up vote cancels many down votes, so even if a question gets some downward motion initially - eventually the votes it deserves should arrive and the reputation bump associated.

Answer (score 6):

Regional Settings in Preferences sets your "localization" preferences.  In other words, it sets the language, the decimal notation, the date format, etc. for your *local* computer.

It does not *force* remote computers to conform to the standard you selected.

Whether or not a website displays in your preferred language has to do with the website/web developer and whether or not they chose to implement a translation mechanism or alternate websites based on country of the visitor (this is usually done by a combination of location and browser agent string).

If the website you visit doesn't provide either an English version or an automatic translation feature, there are online translators available.  I prefer to use [Bing Translator](https://www.bing.com/translator/)

Comment: @Taylor - If the answer was helpful, please up vote.  If it solved your issue, you can accept to let the community know it was solved.  As a nudge in the right direction, I would remove your comments - it's not good to get into arguments.  I'll correct (and be corrected), but not engage.  Oh, and Welcome to Ask Different!